# Retry S3 read/write operations in R

Tags: r, amazon-s3

I've written a Shiny app that is in essense a front end to data stored on S3. There is a lot of reading and writing data to an S3 bucket going when the app is running, and most of the time this is working flawlessly. However, it happens some times that a read or write operation times out and the app breaks as a result.

In other situations where I rely on data from API's using the HTTR package, I use the package's `RETRY` function, which allows me to retry a GET/POST call a specified number of times, like so:

```
RETRY("GET", "http://httpbin.org/status/500", times = 5)

# Request failed [500]. Retrying in 1 seconds...
# Request failed [500]. Retrying in 3 seconds...
# Request failed [500]. Retrying in 1 seconds...
# Request failed [500]. Retrying in 15.5 seconds...
# Response [http://httpbin.org/status/500]
#  Date: 2019-04-15 19:14
#  Status: 500
#  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
#<EMPTY BODY>
```

My question is whether I can do something similar with my connection to S3?

My read operations mostly look something like this:

```
object <- aws.s3::save_object(s3_file_path, bucket, file = local_file_path, overwrite = TRUE)
data <- readRDS(local_file_path)
```

And my write operations like this:

```
file_name <- "test.txt"
aws.s3::put_object(local_file_path, object = file_name, bucket)
```

Comment: Seems like `?purrr::insistently` may be what you want

Comment: I think you're right! Looks very promising. Thank you.